# fastest way to query a field that has more than one possible matching value

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables.

First table is called `professions`, and those are indexed by ID. So each profession now has a unique ID associated with it.

My second table is called `contacts`, and in there I have a `profession` field that right now only hold the ID that a certain profession is associated with.

My problem is that what if I have a contact that has more than one profession associated with it.

What would be the best way to query the table and ways to store the professions of a contact. I didn't want to do is create a field to just store a 0 or 1 int for each profession I have. The reason is because I want to dynamically grow the professions table and have the numbers reflect any dynamic changes on my site when I query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a many-to-many relationship. To implement that in MySQL you should use a linking table. So `professions` and `contacts` should have an id in each table, but no foreign keys, and you create a new table called `profession_contact_links` or something, containing its own id, and `profession_id` and `contact_id`, which are both foreign keys to the respective tables. Then you can have many contacts linked with each profession, and many professions linked with each contact. To connect the two main tables together in a select you will need two joins, and what they are will depend on what exactly you want to select.

Comment: so when you delete a contact it will cascade the delete in the professions_contact_link table?

Comment: If you are using InnoDB then you can set them to be registered foreign keys, in which case I understand deletion would be cascaded to the links record. In general I tend not to use InnoDB's foreign key system though, and just make sure I delete links when deleting the original record (it is only one extra query).

Answer (score 2):

The standard solution to this modelling issue is called a link table.

Basically it is a table that contains the ids of the two tables that are linked, so you would have a link table with to columns and a primary key that is both of those columns:

```
(profession_id, contact_id)
```

or the other order... doesn't matter that much, but the order can affect performance, the key you will be searching on most often is the one you want first.

You then use either `SELECT ... IN (...)` or `SELECT ... JOIN ...` to query the data that you are after.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want and how you want to find it, i'd suggest `rlike` or `in`

`SELECT ... FROM <table> WHERE <column name> RLIKE "^id1|id2|id3$"`

This will find any cell that **contains** any of those three terms

or use

`SELECT ... FROM <table> Where <column name> IN ('id1','id2','id3')`

this will find any cell that is **equals** to one of those three.

Comment: my contacts table has 10,000,000 records. what would the performace be on RLIKE?

Comment: I am not sure...but my guess would be that RLIKE is slow, LIKE is slow, and In is fast(er)? But again I'm not sure...sorry